# SQL statement to switch values

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have several tables where a field is for priority (1 to 5). Problem here is that different projects have been using 5 as highest and some 1 for highest and I going to harmonize this.

My easy option is to create a temp table and copy the data over and switch as this table:
1 -> 5
2 -> 4
3 -> 3
4 -> 2
5 -> 1

I'm not that good with SQL but it feels that there should be an easy way to switch those values right off with an statement but I do have concerns of when there are huge amount of data and if something goes wrong half way then the data will be in a mess.

Should I just go with my temp table solution or should do you have a nice way of doing this straight in SQL? (Oracle 10g is being used)

Many thanks!

Comment: You say SOME projects - so don't forget to add a WHERE clause to the queries provided in the answers!

Comment: If you have a concern about how the solution works or whether you will have a mess, first, do not do it straight on prod and second make a backup of that data as it stood before you made the change. If you have auditing, you can use this instead. That way the information before the change is always avaliable to reverse if you see that it went bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

simply update the second table like this, a temp table is not needed because you are just reversing the priority:

```
update table_2
set priority = 6-priority;
```

Comment: Don't we stil need a where clause since the OP stated only some were reversed?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CASE statement

```
case PRIORITY
  when 5 then 1
  when 4 then 2
  when 3 then 3
  when 2 then 4
  when 1 then 5
  else PRIORITY
end
```

Edit: texBlues' solution is much better, but I leave this here for cases where the maths isn't as neat.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that no 'mess' results if the update goes awry, use a transaction. Building on tekBlues solution (+1 for this).

```
START TRANSACTION;

update table_2
set priority = 6-priority;

...

COMMIT;
```

This is especially valid if you want to update multiple tables in one go. Single statements are implicitely handled, as hainstech pointed out in his comment correctly.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle user, but surely a single statement is always run in an implicit or explicit transaction regardless?